# Вирус в БИОСе? Такое может быть?

Tags: linux, bios, firewall

Всем привет!

Друзья, есть вопрос: возможно ли заражение БИОС трояном?

Подробней: есть пара старых ноутов, в которых сетевуха сама по себе может оживать после выключения этих ноутов при включении компа или нового ноута) Да. Два ноута юзаю по работе( документы какие - то храню, скрипты на Питоне или на ПХП, копии стареньких проектов и т.д. ), на них стоит Линукс( Parrot Os, если точно. Нравится эта операционка в первую очередь за то, что в коробке куча драйверов, которые на "ура" подходят для моих стареньких ноутов( к примеру, один из них - Lenovo e535 и с дровами на видюху когда - то очень "парился") ), да и радует из коробки уже установленные апач, энжинкс и т.д., и т.п.. Иногда сериалы какие - то смотрю.

Так вот, недавно заметил, что когда ноуты выключаю, а потом через полчаса или час включаю новый ноут или комп, то на роутере обнаруживаю загорание светодиодов, показывающих активность сетевых карт на моих выключенных ноутах.
Залез в настройки ноутов и обнаружил выключенным "Wake on lan". Пытался сам даже отправлять "магические пакеты" на ноуты, думая, что все - таки каким - то образом "wake on lan" включен. Нет, ничего вот также не включается. Вот и думаю. Просто раньше был случай, когда ноуты были взломаны и на них был установлен "вредонос". Попытка пропинговать сеть nmap или отправить arp - запросы, чтобы увидеть активные хосты в сети( с помощью arp-scan --localnet ), или просто запустить Ваяшарк с сетевой картой в "promisc" - режиме, ни к чему не приводят - просто горят светодиоды, но никакого дополнительного трафика я не вижу.

В общем, интересует мнение. Возможно ли в БИОС установить трояна, который по событию включается( ну, т.е. ноут не выключается совсем, а сетевуха снифферит определенный пакет( не "магический" при wake on lan ), который разрабом вируса был указан, и далее включается сетевуха и далее, подключаясь через трояна, через DMA( dirrect memory access ), кто - то на ноут залезть может? Или это я перемудрил с домыслами?

Comment: *Возможно ли в БИОС установить трояна, который по событию включается* Да, но нет. То есть записать его туда можно, но в выключенном состоянии никакой код, в т.ч. код трояна, не исполняется. *Вирус в БИОСе? Такое может быть?* Не просто может быть - реально существует.

Comment: а вообще intel таких «троянов», которые работают, когда тачка выключена (в т.ч. в ACPI S5), штатно прошивает в свои чипсеты. см. *Intel ME*

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а Интел тут причём? Тоже самое делают все серверные платформы, которые соответствуют спецификациям BMC, более того, в современных больших процессорах по несколько разных микроконтроллеров стоит, так что...

Comment: @0andriy, поправь меня, если я не прав, но у BMC обычно нет неограниченного доступа ко всему оборудованию в т.ч. к содержимому памяти и жёстких дисков, а у «микроконтроллеров больших процессоров» нет доступа к сети 24/7, независимо от статуса питания, (разве что в телефонах, но это отдельная история)...

Comment: Почитай про IPMI. ARM хитрецы, конечно, умалчивают (точнее не рекламируют направо и налево), что на серверном оборудовании у них это тоже есть...